# Using a macro inside the axis options for pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, expansion, pgfkeys

I want to create an macro to replace the string '{a,b,c}' in my code:

```
xticklabels={a,b,c}
```

so I set

```
\newcommand\inputnames{a,b,c}
xticklabels=\inputnames
```

but this gives me the same result as `xticklabels={{a,b,c}}`, which is different in my case. I suppose that it comes from an unwanted expansion of my macro but I can't find how to prevent it.

The complete code is bellow:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\inputnames}{a,b,c}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xtick={1,2,3},xticklabels=\inputnames]
\addplot coordinates {(1,-1)(2,-3)(3,-4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xtick={1,2,3},xticklabels={a,b,c}]
\addplot coordinates {(1,-1)(2,-3)(3,-4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use

```
xticklabels/.expand once=\inputnames
```

which expands the argument to `xticklabel` once before actually applying it. (There’s also `.expand twice` and `.expanded`.)

Otherwise when the `xticklabels` are read, the parser only find one label, namely `\xticklabel` which is then given to the node that typesets this. Firstly here the macro is expanded.

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\inputnames}{a,b,c}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xtick={1,2,3},xticklabels/.expand once=\inputnames]
\addplot coordinates {(1,-1)(2,-3)(3,-4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]